# i can't get the has-error text field in bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii

i've been trying to learn yii recently and so i started to work on an simple form with bootstrap. im using yii 1.1.x version not version 2 so i had to install bootstrap manually and write coding based on it.
anyway coming back to the problem it seems that my has-success class is being called correctly by jquery but it does'nt seem so for the has-error...
can someone help and im grateful for your help

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#contact_name').on('input', function() {
        var input = $(this);
        var is_name = input.val();
        if (is_name) {
            $('#contact_name').removeClass("has-success").addClass('has-error');
        } else {
            $('#contact_name').removeClass("has-error").addClass('has-success');
        }
    });

});
</script>
<h1>Example Form Validation</h1>
<br>
<div class="form " id="cla">
    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm',array( 'id' =>'form','htmlOptions'=> array('class'=> 'form-horizontal', 'name' => 'forvalidate', 'id' => 'registration-form' ))); ?>
    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-5" id='contact_name'>
            <?php echo $form->label($model,'name',$htmloptions = array('class'=>'control-label ',)); ?>
            <div class="controls">
                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('name' =>'name' ,'class'=>'form-control col-xs-5', 'aria-describedby'=>'inputSuccess4Status')); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
<!-- form -->
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$('#contact_name').on('input', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var is_name = input.val();
    if (!is_name) {
        $('#contact_name').parent().removeClass("has-success").addClass('has-error');
    } else {
        $('#contact_name').parent().removeClass("has-error").addClass('has-success');
    }
});
```

I think "has-error" and "has-success" classes don't apply directly on the input but the div where the inputs are

Comment: the has-error is not working at all but the success is working perfectly

Comment: I think it's `if (!is_name)` instead of  `if (is_name)`

Answer (score 2):

You have to add these classes. See the highlighted code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#contact_name').on('input', function() {
        var is_name = $(this).val();
        if (is_name) {
            $('#contact_name').removeClass("has-success").addClass('has-error');
            //                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        } else {
            $('#contact_name').removeClass("has-error").addClass('has-success');
            //                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: @Khader Go to `jsfiddle.net` and input your whole code

Comment: jsfiddle is not supporting bootstrap so i can't run the code there